# TinyMCE Yeoman cannot be built

Tags: typescript, npm, tinymce, yeoman, tinymce-plugins

I am creating a new plugin for TinyMCE using Yeoman generator as suggested in the [official documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/yeoman-generator/).

However, even if I create a completely empty project, using `yo tinymce` and `npm install`, the project can be watched (`npm start`), but when I try to build it (`npm run build`) it fails on the following list of errors (highly shortened):

```
Running "clean:dirs" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "tslint:plugin" (tslint) task
>> 6 files lint free.

Running "shell:command" (shell) task
node_modules/@ephox/agar/lib/main/ts/ephox/agar/api/DragnDrop.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'File'.
node_modules/@ephox/agar/lib/main/ts/ephox/agar/api/DragnDrop.d.ts(15,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'File'.

// A lot other node_modules error lines here

node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts(2745,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.
node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts(2751,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Window'.
node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts(2752,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.
node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts(2752,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ShadowRoot'.
Warning: Command failed: tsc
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 6
npm ERR! myproject@1.0.0 build: `grunt`
npm ERR! Exit status 6
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@1.0.0 build script.
```

Do you have any ideas on how to overcome this problem? I've tried to build the code on Windows as well as WSL.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was resolved by adding additional lines of code to `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

It will exclude `node_modules` directory from checking during compiling.
More information can be found here:
https://dd.engineering/blog/typescript-the-skiplibcheck-option-explained